# c# reshow window by click on notifyicon

Tags: c#, forms, system, notifyicon, tray

I'm new with c# but know c++ and c, my problem is that I can't get my form to show up again after it got minimized to the system tray.

That's the code I used to hide it:

```
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        bool cursorNotInBar = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Contains(Cursor.Position);

        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized && cursorNotInBar)
        {
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you try to show it up again?

Comment: With this.Show() and the OnClick Event.

Comment: Why would you leave out the code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to **undo** the changes you made to the form to make it hide...to make it display again:

```
    private void notifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.Show();
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for tip about MouseClick. I've tried with NotifyIcon.Click event and failed.

Answer (score 0):

on notifyIcon click event try:

```
this.Show();
```

(I'm not sure but this one could work too: this.Visible = true)

by the way try to handle OnClosing event on your form instead of OnResize

(I have suitable code in home, when i got there ill share it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **this.Show()** to show the form again after minimized. If this is not working, just tell me, will provide another solution.

Comment: Did try that before asking :(

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share your code, so that i will try it out and let you know.

Comment: I solved it today:

private void notifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.Activate();
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;
        }